# Assigning random variables random values

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm making the game 2048 in python as my 'Hello world'
The game is played with a 4*4 grid 
I have assigned each 'square' it own variable as such
sqr1 = 0
sqr2 = 0
sqr...  up to 16
( I'm sure there are better ways but I'm more worried about my current problem. )

In the beginning of the game 2 randomly selected squares are randomly assigned either the value of 2, or the value of 4.

I already have the 2 'squares' randomly selected and the random values are selected as well but I have no idea how to assign the randomly selected 'squares' the random values chosen.

This is what I have right now

```
sqr16 = 0

# Randomly selected 'squares'
Random_Number_1 = random.randint(1, 16)
Random_Number_2 = random.randint(1, 16)
while(Random_Number_1 == Random_Number_2):
    Random_Number_1 = random.number(1, 16)

# Assign the randomly selected 'squares' random values.
# I know this is 100% not going to work as i wish it to work
sqr[Random_number_1] = random.randint([2], [4])
sqr[Random_Number_2] = random.randint([2], [4])
```

( I haven't put any of this in to the python editor, this was written with a txt application on Chromebook. And please be simple, this is my Hello world the most complex thing I know is defining functions. )

Comment: Don't use dynamic *variables*, use a *container*, like a `list` or a `dict`.

Comment: "I'm sure there are better ways but I'm more worried about my current problem." Your current problem is a direct result of you not using a better way to implement this. I would worry about it more.

Answer (score 2):

" I have assigned each 'square' it own variable as such sqr1 = 0 sqr2 = 0 sqr... up to 16 "

This will be a massive pain for you to deal with if you keep this format.  To continue your way, you'd need code like:

```
if(Random_number_1 == 0):
    sqr1 = random.randint([2], [4])
if(Random_number_1 == 1):
    sqr2 = random.randint([2], [4])
if(Random_number_1 == 2):
    sqr3 = random.randint([2], [4])
.........
```

If instead, you keep your squares in a list like:

`sqr = [0]*16`

Then accessing them is easy! One line instead of 32:

```
sqr[Random_Number_1] = random.randint([2], [4])
```

Answer (score 1):

Using a list will make things a bit easier. Since you have a 4x4 grid, you have 16 slots. Initialize a list of zeros or whatever value you would like. Then randomly select a slot and assign it a value until you have at least two cells that contain either 2 or 4.

```
import random

grid = [0 for i in range(16)]

while sum([i > 0 for i in grid]) < 2:      # Make sure we have 2 cells selected
    loc = random.choice(range(len(grid)))  # Pick a random spot
    grid[loc] = random.choice([2, 4])      # Give it a random value

print(grid)
```

The output from running this 5 times is as follows

```
[0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0]
[4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 2]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0]
```

Then, if you want to convert it to a 2D list to make it simple enough to know which cells align with others, you can just chunk it out and you're ready to play!

```
grid = [grid[n*4: n*4+4] for n in range(4)]
print(grid)
# [[0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 4], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 2, 0, 0]]
```

Then, if you really want to have fun, you can throw it into a function, and set some variables to play with different size boards!

```
import random

def create_grid(size, starting_tiles):

    grid = [0 for i in range(size**2)]

    while sum([i > 0 for i in grid]) < starting_tiles:
        loc = random.choice(range(len(grid)))
        grid[loc] = random.choice([2, 4])

    return [grid[n*size: n*size+size] for n in range(size)]

pp.pprint(create_grid(4, 2))
#[[0, 0, 2, 0], 
# [0, 0, 0, 0], 
# [0, 0, 0, 0], 
# [0, 0, 4, 0]]

pp.pprint(create_grid(5, 3))
#[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
# [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
# [0, 2, 0, 0, 4],
# [0, 0, 0, 0, 2],
# [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```